# how to set exim4 sender_helo_name on debian

Tags: linux, debian, exim

am using exim4 mail server on my vps running debian 8.9 , problem is i can get email but cant send mails , so when i send mail from roundcube to gmail i get error

> SMTP Error (550): Failed to set sender (Access denied - Invalid HELO
>   name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)).

so i check exim4 template and debug it and found that $sender_helo_name is set to my server ip address. so i was wondering how to set $sender_helo_name value to my site domain

update exim main log :

```
2017-09-28 09:33:56 H=localhost (198.50.220.183) [127.0.0.1] rejected MAIL <contactus@useotools.com>: Access denied - Invalid HELO name ( 198.50.220.183) (See RFC2821 4.1.3)
2017-09-28 09:36:23 no host name found for IP address 123.56.151.114
2017-09-28 09:36:24 no host name found for IP address 123.56.151.114
2017-09-28 09:39:01 1dxQbF-0003dy-6j <= root@useotools.com U=root P=local S=1044
2017-09-28 09:39:01 1dxQbF-0003dy-6j => root <root@useotools.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery
2017-09-28 09:39:01 1dxQbF-0003dy-6j Completed
2017-09-28 09:43:17 no IP address found for host 207-101-169-181.fibertel.com.ar (during SMTP connection from [181.169.101.207])
2017-09-28 09:43:18 no IP address found for host 207-101-169-181.fibertel.com.ar (during SMTP connection from [181.169.101.207])
2017-09-28 09:46:36 no IP address found for host ip-187.94.111-100.globalwave.com.br (during SMTP connection from [187.94.111.100])
2017-09-28 09:46:37 no IP address found for host ip-187.94.111-100.globalwave.com.br (during SMTP connection from [187.94.111.100])
2017-09-28 09:53:15 no host name found for IP address 41.191.224.5
2017-09-28 09:53:16 no host name found for IP address 41.191.224.5
2017-09-28 09:54:23 exim 4.84_2 daemon started: pid=15145, -q30m, listening for SMTP on port 25 (IPv4) port 587 (IPv4) port 2525 (IPv4) and for SMTPS on port 465 (IPv4)
```

Comment: Question: In your log, it says no host name for 123.56.151.114. Is this your IP address or one of your clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the macro MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME and set it to the desired name.  Typically this would be something like mail.example.com or smtp.example.com.  If you are using split configuration, use a file in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main`.  Otherwise, use `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros`.

The 550 error is being sent by the receiving server to indicate your HELO name is invalid.   It should be set to the same value as the PTR record for your servers IP address.  To set the PTR record you need a static IP address and the co-operation of your provider.  You also need a corresponding A record for the name of your mail server.  This will enable rDNS validation of the name.  Your MX record should point to this name.

Also look at setting up an SPF record for your mail server and your domain.

Using your VPS provider's relay server may be a simpler solution.  Use a `smarthost` configuration with local mail.  Configure the relay server as the smarthost server.  Modify your SPF record to indicate that the relay server can send mail for your domain.

Comment: ya i set macro MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME in /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs   also spf records are set in my vesta cp , however i added it for mail domain  when i debug $sender_helo_name is still server ip

Comment: i haved exim mail log

Comment: i have set hostname in /etc/sysctl.conf 
kernel.hostname = useotools.com
kernel.domainname = useotools.com
but still no luck :( i wonder why exim is setting server ip for heloname

Comment: @user889030 You need to configure exim not the kernel.  It common for a mail server to present a different name than the host it runs on.  Check DNS as well.  It would be much easier to assist you if you provided your mail server's domain name.  You will need to restart exim after altering the configuration.

Comment: my mail server is : mail.useotools.com   ... incoming mails are ok , just that outgoing mail issue , with helo name

Comment: @user889030  You have no PTR record which will get you blocked by many sites, but is not listed in the Spamhaus blacklists.  Your server identifies itself as `220 useotools.com ESMTP Exim 4.84_2 Sat, 30 Sep 2017 04:38:03 +0500` not with an IP address.

Comment: thanks its fixed now, it was issue it host side they have blocked it